# How to send the same (duplicate) TCP packet in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, scapy

I am sending this custom packet over a TCP socket

```
pkt = IP(len=16384, src='192.168.240.243', dst=ip,
        id=RandShort(), ttl=64)/TCP(sport=5000,
        dport=5000, flags="S", window=200,
        options=[('MSS', 1460), ('WScale', 2)])/CustomLayer(type=1, update=2)/"SENT"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:    
    s.connect((ip, 5000))
except socket.error:
    print 'User not connected'

spkt = str(pkt)
s.send(spkt)
```

The packet is correctly sent and received, but I can't send more than one. If I try for example to include this in a while(i<10), only one packet is received, the others are marked as [TCP Retransmission] looking in Wireshark.

How can I send the packet more than once within the same socket?

Comment: I have no experience, but I guess you'd need to change the id attribute of the packet so that the under laying IP stack will think it's a different packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your packets have the same ID, so they are the same packets, and therefore discarded as duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. However I think I will switch to UDP protocol.